Can't figure out how to change column type in bigquery
I looked it up and it seems like I can just run a query similar to the one below, however when I execute it, I get the following error: Column not found: struct1.struct2.CurrentlyStringDataType at [2:1]
ALTER TABLE `project.dataset.table`
ALTER COLUMN `struct1.struct2.CurrentlyStringDataType`
SET DATA TYPE INTEGER;

Any idea why this is happening? I used the google doc for this too: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#sql

Hi spider , based on the error you are getting when your Column is too nested .    column_name: The name of the top level column you're altering(supported). Modifying subfields is not supported. You can refer to this doc once

Ah great thank you, how did I miss that

Hi @Spider,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you.  do consider accepting and upvoting if it helps, as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research.

Hi @spider based on the error you are getting  Column not found:  , it may come when your Column is too nested .
It’s supported when-  column_name : The name of the top level column you're altering .
Modifying subfields is not supported.
